# Inconsistency in one of the "view more" links on profiles

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

[image]

The icon on the left of the *view more* link is not following the harmony of the universe. It might even make us think it is one of our accounts.

I suggest removing the little icon to restore the balance in the universe.

Comment: It was a link only when it was linking to an "accounts" tab on site's profile itself, like the other links are. Now that it links to StackExchange.com instead, it *is* different from the other links.

Comment: @TheElementofMagic but... it took me a lot of work to be able to merge sad+angry+worried in a single smiley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [The Element of Magic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/134300/the-element-of-magic) said, that link is for a page that is external to the site you are in, while the other links you are referring are for pages in the site you are visiting.

Talking of consistency, all the links in that block takes you to external sites, and they have an icon. I don't see why that particular link (which takes you to an external site) should not have an icon.

[image: screenshot]